# DocuSign Integration Connector

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to build a DocuSign integration (connector) to our application.

Use Case: We have multiple customer and some customer has multiple account. We intend to use Authorization Code Grant/JWT Grant flow to connect customer account to our application. We would be storing access token, refresh token & expiration date for each connection.

Question:

We notice ISV is the recommended route. We would like to understand more on this:

1. After creation of an ISV/Partner DocuSign account, how do we integrate it with multiple customers' account?
2. Can we use the same integration key + client secret in ISV/Partner account to retrieve access token an make calls to eSignature API (i.e to send envelopes and signature) for multiple customers' account?
3. How would the go-live process occur in this scenario?

Other than the above, are there option other than ISV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISV simply means that you build integration to be used by many customers, each with their own account. However, an IK can be used with many different accounts, whether you're an ISV or not.

> After creation of an ISV/Partner DocuSign account, how do we integrate
> it with multiple customers' account?

You create an IK (integration key which is like a clientId) and that can be used to authenticate with any DocuSign account.

> Can we use the same integration key + client secret in ISV/Partner
> account to retrieve access token an make calls to eSignature API (i.e
> to send envelopes and signature) for multiple customers' account?

Yes, this is called Auth Code Grant. Using this method you must interactively log into DocuSign (like providing a password) whenever you use your application.

> How would the go-live process occur in this scenario?

Go-live is the same in all cases. You need to make API calls in the developer environment that comply with the rules (at least 20, no polling, no errors) and then you can start the process. You will need a valid production account to complete the process and promote your IK to production to be used by any customer in production.